# Conditional Spring Security authorization

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

**Background:**

1. Let's assume an application which uses ex.`@PreAuthorize(hasRole('FOO_READER'))` authorization on endpoint/controller level. It all works fine.
2. The `Foo` entity now has an editability flag added. Depending on this flag this entity is locked for editing or not.
3. There is a role added to the system `FOO_LOCKER` which allows to create locked entities, locking existing ones, and editing locked.
4. Now, all the relevant REST endpoints need to be authorized based on the value of passed `editable` value in the passed model in DTO/editability value from DB.
5. The basic logic for creating, including a check for editability would be:

```
public ResponseEntity<FooOutputDto> create(FooInputDto inputDto) {
    if (nonNull(inputDto.getEditable()) && !hasFooLockerAuthority()) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).build();
    }

    Foo foo = fooMapper.map(inputDto);
    Foo createdFoo = fooService.create(foo)
    FooOutputDto outputDto = fooMapper.map(createdFoo);
    return ok(outputDto);
}
```

6. For update and delete it would be something like:

```
public ResponseEntity<FooOutputDto> update(UUID fooId, FooInputDto inputDto) {
    if (!(hasFooLockerAuthority() || fooService.getById(fooId).getEditable())) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).build();
    }

    Foo updatedFoo = fooService.update(fooId, fooMapper.map(inputDto));

    FooOutputDto outputDto = fooMapper.map(updatedFoo);
    return ok(outputDto);
}
```

**Question:**

Now, I hate those checks and I'd love to throw them out of the controller. I wanted to use Spring Security to do that but I don't see how to employ it or rather what functionality of Spring Security to use.

I had an alternative thought to create an aspect, with cutpoint on annotation, and return status forbidden when security check fails.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ***Custom Spring Security Expression***

Read this [post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression) to learn how to do it. You can see the example in practice in the code below.

```java
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject, 'read')")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/foos/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public Foo findById(@PathVariable long id) {
        return new Foo("Sample");
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#foo, 'write')")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/foos")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ResponseBody
    public Foo create(@RequestBody Foo foo) {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I might have not clarified it enough. User1 (authorities FOO_READ, FOO_WRITE) can create or edit  `Foo` with flag `editable=true`. User2 (authorities FOO_READ, FOO_WRITE, FOO_LOCKER) can do all User1 can, but additionally can create `Foo` with `editable=false`, can set `editable` to `false, can edit `Foo` when `editable=false`.